# How to use mySQL with Node.js and Express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm new to using Node.js and Express and I would like to use them with mySQL. I just want to make a simple app. I've tried tutorials but they don't work for me.

Comment: http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beyond the vagueness of this question, I would suggest you try [knex](http://knexjs.org/).

It handles some nice things like connecting to a DB, building queries and supports callbacks and Promises. (Tip: Since you're just starting, use callbacks.)

This is less complicated than an ORM, and a step above writing SQL strings in a mysql connector.

Good luck.